# Determinating Complexity time

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm doing a project for university about how to determinate Complexity assuming that all that is known about an algorithm are their running times depending on the data size.

The types of algorithm I use are polynomial (n2, n3,..,n6), logarithmic and exponential.

For example, an imput of the program it can be:

n       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12 (data size)

T(n)    0,9 /   1,6 /  2,3 /    3,0 /   3,7 /   4,4 /   5,1 /   5,8 /   6,5 /   7,2 /   7,9 /   8,6

So, I've got an algorithm for the polynomial and logarithmic complexity,
For now, the data is maximum 20

polynomial:

```
while answer = -1 and then j > 12 loop
aux:= true;
  for k in 1..j loop
    c := Polynomial(k+1);
    Polynomial(k) := Polynomial(k+1) - Polynomial(k);  
    aux:= aux and abs(Polynomial(k)) < abs (c * 0.005);  --Almost equal
  end loop;
   if aux then
     aux := 19 - j;
     end if;
   j := j-1;
end loop;
```

I've reached a dead end with the exponencial one. 
Could someone give me a hint?
Thank you so much.

Comment: What do the values you gave for `T(n)` mean?

Comment: See also this [*table of common time complexities*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities).

Comment: This isn’t an Ada-related problem. Of course, any Ada compiler would reject `aux := 19 - j`!

Comment: This might be better asked on cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: should be about O(n^2) if i remember from those years ago while is a constant and so is a for both of n.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a stochastic problem i.e. find the best model fit given a set of discrete points. The first thing I would do is determine the type: logarithmic/polynomial/exponential. To do that you can study the discrete derivative at each point. If the value of the first derivative is decreasing => logarithmic. To determine if it is polynomial or exponential again you should study the derivative, but this time not only the first order. The following can be observed: continues derivation of an exponential function is exponential as well while the polynomial one will get linear (derivative close to 0). Hence if after a couple of derivations your value are close to 0 => polynomial.

Having determined the type of the model you would now like to fit your points to that model. You can do it in C++ with the help of [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library and mainly [their implementation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1LevenbergMarquardt.html) of [Levenberg–Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) algorithm